# Mathematica 12.1 crashes when I attempt to save an image as PDF or EPS (but not other formats)

Tags: pdf-format, crash

Has anyone else experienced a bug in Mathematica v.12.1 whereby saving an image as PDF or EPS causes the software to crash? If so, has someone found a cause/solution?

Comment: You've been here a while; you should already be aware that the [tag:bugs] tag **isn't to be used for new questions**.

Comment: But how can I make people aware if not by posting a question? (I apologize for that mistake)

Comment: You can ask a question, surely; but you do not get to add the [tag:bugs] tag without confirmation. Please read the [tag wiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/bugs/info), since you apparently have not done so before.

Comment: Okay, thank your for that information.

Comment: Are you talking about some specific images? Using Mma 12.1 on Linux I can save an image e.g. `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}] ` as PDF or EPS without any issues.

Comment: @vsht and user120911 for clarification's sake, do you mean right-click save-as or `Export`ing the image?

Comment: Click on tab, Save Selection As, PDF ... a second passes, then Mathematics shuts down and nothing is saved. (Windows machine)

Comment: This will perhaps turn out to be platform-specific. It is best in such cases to contact Tech Support with platform details and an example. For what it's worth, I've encountered many such problems using Linux with past versions, though not in 12.0/1. These have been quite a source of frustration, with effects ranging from silently failing to convert, to crashing my session, to the keyboard nipping my pinky.

Comment: @CATrevillian Yes, that's what I mean. No problems on Linux with that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Mathematica 12.1 on Windows 10), saving a notebook in PDF format produces total garbage: pages full of random characters and marks. However, printing notebook with 'Microsoft Print to PDF' generates correct PDF document.